# ¿Cómo añadir una alerta para confirmar o anular un borrado con sweetalert2 JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, sweetalert2

Este es el código *PHP* que borra al usuario:

```
if(isset($_POST['id_del'])){
    $id_user=MysqlQuery::RequestPost('id_del');
    if(MysqlQuery::Eliminar("cliente", "id_cliente='$id_user'")){
        echo 'Guardado';
    }else{ echo 'No guardado';}
}
```

Este es el *HTML*:

```
<form action="" method="POST" style="display: inline-block;">
    <input type="hidden" name="id_del" value="<?php echo $row['id_cliente']; ?>">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</form>
```

*JavaScript* llamada de alerta:

```
<script>
Swal.fire({
    title: '¿Estas seguro?',
    text: "No podras revertirlo!",
    icon: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Eliminar'
}).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
        //codigo php  )
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: lo que puedes hacer es crear una funcion ajax que conecte con la función eliminar en el servidor.

Comment: No puedes ejecutar código PHP desde Sweet Alert, tienes dos opciones: 1. Redirigir a la página que borra el registro. 2. Ejecutar una petición AJAX a esa página